# SQL Server : @dimstartdate and @dimenddate, timeId, what does it do?

Tags: sql-server

Have seen

```
 DTZ.timeid BETWEEN @dimstartdate AND @dimenddate
```

used in some SQL Server queries, but cannot find any literature, or even questions about what it does or achieves.

I have read various things about it using the Max transactionid on the main table in a LEFT JOIN query but cannot be sure.

I'm familiar with Oracle syntax over SQL Server, and have just been experimenting.

If someone could give an explanation, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to ask here. Perhaps if you put it in the context of a complete (but small) query? `BETWEEN` is fairly standard across SQL databases so I'm not sure how you can be familiar with Oracle but find this confusing.

Comment: It's just a **condition** (usually in a `WHERE` clause) that limits the returned rows to those where the `DTZ.timeid` value (probably a date) lies **between** the `@dimstartdate` and the `@dimenddate` values (those are T-SQL **variables** that hold some value)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i am definitely familiar with a 'BETWEEN' statement, i'm having a problem with the '@dimstartdate' and '@dimenddate', evidently i'm unfamiliar with T-SQL variables.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s that was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DTZ.timeid BETWEEN @dimstartdate AND @dimenddate`

In this fragment -

- `DTZ` - is probably a `table alias`. If you scroll up that code, you
  will find somewhere `FROM *<tablename>* AS DTZ`
- `timeid` - is the name of a column in the table that has the alias
  `DTZ`
- `@dimstartdate`& `@dimenddate` - are variables. Again if you scroll
  up, you will find somewhere `DECLARE @dimstartdate, DECLARE @dimenddate`
- `BETWEEN` & `AND` are SQL keywords. Coming from Oracle, I am sure you
  must be familiar with them.

Such code will usually follow `WHERE` and serve as a filter. In this case, they would filter records that have a value in the column `timeid`, which fall between the values passed into the variables - `@dimstartdate & @dimenddate`

Comment: Thanks Raj, my question wasn't clear in that i was only asking for the '@dimstartdate' and '@dimenddate', which you have answered, evidently i'm unfamiliar with T-SQL variables.